# JPA Map<String,String> mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, persistence

How can I map a Map in JPA without using Hibernate's classes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Does not the following work for you?

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Map<String,EntityType> entitytMap = new HashMap<String, EntityType>();
```

`EntityType` could be any entity type, including a `String`.

Comment: I'm a little confused. The question was about mapping a Map<String, String>, but the "best answer" is about a Map<String, EntityType>. Do i miss something?

Comment: EntityType could be any entity type, including a String.

Comment: How many tables does this generate? Is there (1) one for the original class, (2) a join table (with keys for the original class and the entity type) and (3) another table for the EntityType (in the given scenario, a table with just the join table key and the mapped string)? 
This may be a lot of overhead, depending on the Strings saved...

Comment: For a solution without a join table, confer the example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247360/1143126 - it is buggy until hibernate 4.1.6, though.

Comment: This shouldn't generate any join tables - he's not asking to join maps, but a Map.  Not a Map of Maps.

Comment: @ChrisKaminski You are wrong for saying that String is entity type because it does not have Id. You know what I mean and you may know what is called entity.

Comment: For String,String mapping this will not work along. Suggesting to deselect as best answer.

Comment: @ChrisKaminski As has already been mentioned : `String` is not a valid `Entity`

Answer (score 36):

Although answer given by Subhendu Mahanta is correct. But `@CollectionOfElements` is deprecated. You can use `@ElementCollection` instead:

```
@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_RANGE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ID"))
@MapKeyColumn (name="RANGE_ID")
@Column(name="VALUE")
private Map<String, String> attributeValueRange = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

There is no need to create a separate Entity class for the `Map` field. It will be done automatically.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose I have an entity named Book which is having a Map of chapters:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;    
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements;
import org.hibernate.annotations.MapKey;
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable{
@Column(name="BOOK_ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long bookId;    

@CollectionOfElements(targetElement=java.lang.String.class)
@JoinTable(name="BOOK_CHAPTER",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_ID"))
@MapKey (columns=@Column(name="CHAPTER_KEY"))
@Column(name="CHAPTER")
private Map<String,String> chapters;
public Long getBookId() {
    return bookId;
}
public void setBookId(Long bookId) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
}
public Map<String,String> getChapters() {
    return chapters;
}
public void setChapters(Map<String,String> chapters) {
    this.chapters = chapters;
}               

}
```

It works for me.

Comment: +1. And what if i want to retrieve only the chapter 3 of all of these books? I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952625/jpa-category-language-relationship

Comment: @ianaz `select c from Book b join b.chapters c where key(c) = '3'`

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires hibernate-specific annotations. The question was for a solution without.

Answer (score 4):

A working example:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "TABLENAME")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "KEY")
@Column(name = "VALUE")
public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return _map;
}
```

Comment: for a many-to-many relationship, you'd also need  `joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="referencing_column")` within @CollectionTable and `@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="referencing_column_other_table")`