# Querying a Map using JPA 2.0 criteria

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I'm looking for JPA 2 criteria equivalent of this JPQL query :

```sql
select e from Entity e join e.myMap m where KEY(m) = 'myKey' and VALUE(m) = ‘myValue’
```

Thank you !

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246735/hibernate-jpa2-h2-querying-elementcollections-hashmap-by-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested, but I guess this should be OK:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entity> criteria = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> entity = criteria.from(Entity.class);
MapJoin<Entity, String, String> mapJoin = entity.joinMap(Entity_.myMap);
criteria.where(cb.and(cb.equal(mapJoin.key(), "myKey"),
                      cb.equal(mapJoin.value(), "myValue")));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it compiles !
Unfortunately I get this bug now : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580614/jpa-criteriabuilder-join-maps ...