# @PostLoad annotated method doesn't get called in entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to find out why my [`@PostLoad`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PostLoad.html) annotated method never gets invoked after loading the object from the database:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "key.job", targetEntity = ScheduledJobParam.class, orphanRemoval = true)
@XmlTransient
private Set<ScheduledJobParam> paramSet;

@Transient
private Map<String, ScheduledJobParam> params;

@PostLoad
public void indexParameters() {

    this.params = new HashMap<>();

    for(ScheduledJobParam param : this.paramSet) {

        String paramName = param.getKey().getName();
        this.params.put(paramName, param);
    }
}
```

The reason I need it is because children rows are loaded in a `Set` but I would like to put them in a `Map` for easy retrieval by key:

```
public String getParameterValue(String _paramName) {
    String result = null;
    ScheduledJobParam param = this.params.get(_paramName);

    if(param != null) {
        result = param.getValue();
    }

    return result;
}
```

My `JPA` provider is `Hibernate`.

Comment: How do you load the entity? You can also let jpa map into a Map<String, ScheduleJobParam> instead of the set.

Comment: how do I map what goes into the key of the `Map` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853076/jpa-mapstring-string-mapping this looks like a good start

Comment: `@MapKeyColumn (name="PARAM_NAME")` worked for loading a Map but I got a `StackOverflowError` when persisting the data from the Map

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399745/persisting-entity-children-loaded-as-map-causes-stackoverflowerror