# How to represent a Map<EntityType, Integer> relation using JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Order` entity, and a `Product` entity. An order may have a number of  pairs, representing the product and the number sold. What is an approprate relation in JPA to represent it?

(So far I have only found methods to associate a collection of EntityA with EntityB. e.g. EntityA contains a `List<EntityB>`. )

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853076/jpa-mapstring-string-mapping

Comment: @Barath The link you posted is Map<String,Entity>, not Map<Entity, String>

Comment: I think the answer talks about Map<String,EntityType>. Answer is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the quantity is all there is to this association and you do not need to navigate from `Product`→`Order`, you can consider the `Integer quantity` as an element collection and do the following - `Product` stays the same:

```
public class Order {
    @ElementCollection                          // 1
    @CollectionTable(name="ORDER_PRODUCT_QTY")  // 2
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")        // 3
    @Column(name="QUANTITY")                    // 4
    private Map<Product, Integer> quantities;
}
```

1. It is a collection of basic types (integers for the quantity), keyed by the entity
2. It is multivalued, so needs a separate table; you optionally want to specify its name
3. The separate collection table will contain column(s) pointing to the `Order` entity, column(s) pointing to the `Product` and a column for the quantity value itself. This lets you set the name of the FK referencing the `Product` table and is optional.
4. This lets you specify the name of the column holding the quantity value. Optional too.

If you have reasons to believe that this is not enough then you may want to create a distinct entity representing the association, like:

`Order` ← `OrderItem` → `Product`

`Order` has many `OrderItem`s, `Product` has many `OrderItem`s, `Order` has many `Product`s indirectly through `OrderItem`, `Product` can be found in many `Order`s, indirectly through `OrderItem` and the quantity is in the `OrderItem`. Representing this kind of "relation with value" as an entity is more flexible than collection mapping.

Answer (score 0):

you have to map entity like

In Order.jave

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_Id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Product> product = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

In Product.jave

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_Id", referencedColumnName = "product_Id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order order;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the above code but it is not working for me.
Below is  my code.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="content_package_component_level_languages_language_assessment_map", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="language_assessment_map_key", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Column(name="language_assessment_map")
private Map<Lang, Integer> languageAssessmentMap;
```