# Java: Best way to save HashMap in Database? Serialise and store as BLOB or add another table with 3 Columns (id, key, value)?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Working with JasperReports where user can save report's parameter `HashMap<String, Object>` in DB so that it can be used later for auto scheduling and regenerate that report again.

Currently Report Parameters are being stored as string and then encoded into bytes as BLOB i.e. `rs.setParameters(reportParams.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));`

This approach is expensive (when auto scheduling triggers) as an overhead to regenerate parameters again and also creates problem with complex parameter values.

I want to change the approach of saving HashMap, So what would that be ?

I can either keep the DB schema as it is and save reportParam by serialising it and deserialise when required again? like shown below, Or would it be better to add another table with 1..* multiplicity, to store parameters separately for each report?

Or is there is any better approach I'm missing ? Also concerned with performance when retrieving reportParams back.  Thanks.

```
public static byte[] serialise(Object obj) {

    byte[] bytearray = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutStream;
    try {
        objectOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutStream);
        objectOutStream.writeObject(obj);
        bytearray = byteOutStream.toByteArray();
        objectOutStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bytearray;
}

public static ReportParameters deSerialize(byte[] byteArray) throws IOException
{
    ReportParameters reportParam = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream byteInstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    ObjectInputStream objectInStream;

    try {
        objectInStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteInstream);
        reportParam = (ReportParameters)objectInStream.readObject();
        objectInStream.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return reportParam ;
}
```

Comment: do you the requirement to update the hashmap ever.

Comment: Store the data properly in a database table. There should be plenty of examples out there on persisting maps via JPA e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853076/jpa-mapstring-string-mapping

Comment: @Dinesh No, Once Scheduled user reportParam hashmap can never be updated.

Comment: How about saving it as json?

Comment: Have you tested serializing and deserializing the HashMap?  Have you benchmarked it and compared the performance to your current method?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yeah its tested and working now. Compared to previous implementation, serialise/deserialise is better. param handling when required gets simplified. Like param with complex values, for instance I had report which includes whole query as param, which was causing issue. I believe saving params in separate table would've been more efficient implementation, but as my reportParams wont be changing that often i went for this one. As long as you handling your Object conversion its all good. Posted the question before implementing it, i've tested it now, pretty much satisfied.