# Efficient way to store multilanguage String data in Spring application

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Is there any best practice to store a multilanguage string using the Spring / Spring boot framework?
For instance, I am designing an Account class.

```
    public class Account {

        private String nameEn;
        private String nameDe;
        
        // getters and setters are omitted

    }
```

Is there an already designed class to store such kind of fields in one field on the Entity level?
Or is it better to design my own class with @Embedded annotation like below?

```
    class MultilingualString {

        private String stringEn;
        private String stringDe;

        public String getString(String locale){
            // get string by locale like "en", "ru"
        }
    
        public String getString(Locale locale){
            // get string by locale
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Not seeing any code, really.

Comment: Please define i18n messages_xxx.properties in resource. Then inject MessageSource to get message info in class. Here is [guide](https://lokalise.com/blog/spring-boot-internationalization/)

Comment: Well, there is `Map<String, String>`, where the key is the locale, e.g. `en`, `en-US`, `de-DE`, ... --- For JPA, you'd define it as shown in this answer: [JPA Map<String,String> mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061468/5221149)