# Spring findAll() method in CrudRepository doesn't return derived entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have the following application, which has one entity called `Product` that inherits two other entities (Product > Bike, Product > Wheel). Controllers look like this:

```java
public abstract class ProductController<T extends Product> {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService<T> productService;
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody T product) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.save(product));
    }
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity get() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.findAll());
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products/categories/bikes")
public class BikeController extends ProductController<Bike> {}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products/categories/wheels")
public class WheelController extends ProductController<Wheel> {}
```

Entities:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    public Product() {}
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Bike extends Product {
    private String color;
    public Bike() {}
    //getters and setters
}
@Entity
public class Wheel extends Product {
    private Double diameter;
    public Wheel() {}
    //getters and setters
}
```

Product repository:

```java
public interface ProductRepository<T extends Product> extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {}
```

Product service:

```java
@Service
public class ProductService<T extends Product> {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository<T> productRepository;
    public T save(T product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }
    public Iterable<T> findAll() { return productRepository.findAll(); }
}
```

After running the program it creates three tables for each entity. If i call the `post` method from the concrete controller it adds the entity to its table. But the findAll() method returns entities not from the concrete table but from the product table. So my question is why is this happening (even if i specified the Entity type in the repository)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achive is impossible because `Bike` is a subtype of `Product` in java *but not* for JPA. In the Database it usally split into different Tables for each Subtype and only the tables (seen by JPA as entites) can be queried. So a Spring Repository can't query it either, because it uses JPA internally.

Please take a look here and read more about jpa inheritance: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Generally: It is bad pratice to have different table for each Type of Product. Everytime you add a new Product you would have to add a whole new class and table in database. It is best practice to just have a single entity/class (and thus a single table) for `Product` and a field to distinguish between different types of products. In it's simplest form a `String productType`, but i would recommand using a seperate Entity `ProductType` with an id and name (in its simplest form) and have a `@OneToMany` relation between `Product` and `ProductType`. Additonal data like `color` and `diameter` could be stored using a field of type `Map` with `@ElementCollection` or in a another entity for (dynamic) additional data (as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061468/7142748).